# AuthService in Angular2

Tags: angular, authentication, service, angular2-jwt

I'm currently building an app in angular2. I therefore implemented an AuthService that handles signin, signup etc. 
If a user signed in the id_token (angular2-jwt) is stored in localStorage. The roles and permission of the user are stored in `AuthService.userRoles` and `AuthService.userPerms`.

A boolean property `AuthService.isAuthenticated` uses the function `tokenNotExpired()` from angular2-jwt which returns false if a user is signed out or the token stored in localStorage is expired. If a user signed in the `AuthService.isAuthenticated` is updated to `true`;

I got routes that use an AuthGuard that only allows **authenticated** users to activate this route by checking the `AuthService.isAuthenticated` property.

If a certain route looks like this:

```
{
  path: "somewhere",
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {
    permissions: [
      "add:some",
      "edit:some"
    ]
  }
}
```

the same AuthGuard checks if the current signed in user has the required permissions by matching `AuthService.userPerms` with the route's  `data.permissions`. **Which works as well.**

My app uses a "main component". This main component is "public" and does **not** use the AuthGuard. It is bootstrapped inside the main `app.module` and has **no own route**. Inside the template of this main parent Component I got the app wide navigation.

Inside this navigation are buttons to routes which are protected by the AuthGuard and are therefore accessible only if a user is signed in and **has certain permissions or roles** if required by the route. For example

```
<button [routerLink]="/somewhere">Somewhere</button>
```

If the user clicks this button and is **not** authorized he is redirected to an `unauthorized` route. **Works so far**

**I want to prevent that** by making these buttons only visible if the user is able to activate the routes.

```
<button [routerLink]="/somewhere"
  *ngIf="isAuthorized["buttonSomewhere"]">
  Somewhere
</button>
```

Therefore inside the main AppComponent (which handles the navigation) I want to **check** the userPermissions for each button inside the template and store the result in an object like this:

```
/* AppComponent */
public isAuthorized = {
   buttonSomewhere = true;
}
```

This **check** is handled by `AuthService.isAuthorized(theRouteToBeActivated)` which is called inside the AppComponent constructor and matches the routes `data.permission` with the users permissions stored in `AuthService.userPerms`.

The problem is, since the AppComponent is **public** and not protected by AuthGuard, that the constructor runs when the user is not signed in, which is right. At this point the called `AuthService.isAuthorized(theRouteToBeActivated)` returns false and stores the value in

```
/* AppComponent */
public isAuthorized = {
  buttonSomewhere = false;
}
```

which is right as well. So if a user is signed out he does not see the buttons to routes he could not activate.

**BUT the problem is:** after the user signed in the `AuthService.isAuthorized(theRouteToBeActivated)` called in the AppComponents constructor is **NOT** called again, and

```
/* AppComponent */
public isAuthorized = {
  buttonSomewhere = false;
}
```

remains as it is. But after the user signed in the function needs to be called again so that it returns true and changes

```
/* AppComponent */
public isAuthorized = {
  buttonSomewhere = true;
}
```

so that the buttons in the template are **now visible to the signed in user**. At the moment I need to reload the app inside the browser. Then the buttons are visible to the signed in user. But I don't want a reload.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by using an authorised guard in the routes parameters. There is a difference between authenticate and authorise. Check the following link.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: my problem is that a AuthGuard manages to make a component accessible only if a user is authenticated already. I know how this works and already implemented this on components I need it. But I need to check the `AuthService.isAuthenticated` property in components that are "public" to display certain content for example a navigation that changes whether the user is singed in or not.

Comment: Max, it depends on how you are handling authentication. I don't know exactly but you can use an *ngIf if there is a token in local storage. I guess that can help you.